# url rewrite or redirect in reactjs

Tags: php, reactjs, url-rewriting, url-routing, redirect

I have a react app and the folder structure like below :

```
+ src
    + client
        + app
            + actions
            + components
            + config
            + lang
            + public
            .
            .
            .
    + server
        + lumen-api
            .
            .
            .
```

in this point I send a request to server side with this url : '/api/login' and this request go to 'http://localhost:8080/api/login' . I seperate the client and server so I guess I can not use the htaccess and the question is :

> How can I redirect or rewrite the url which start 'api' so that it goes to the server/lumen-api section?

When I send a request like '/api/login' I want it the request should go to '/server/lumen-api/auth/login' but I want to show the url like '/api/login'.

> How could I do this ?